# Simplification of complexity of a function with two arguments in terms of Big O

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Let's say we have the following complexity:

```
T(n, k) = n^2 + n + k^2 + 15*k + 123
```

Where we do not know anything about relations between `n` and `k`.

I could say that in terms of Big O complexity will be the following:

```
T(n) = O(n^2 + n + k^2 + 15*k)
```

Can I simplify it further and drop only `15` constant or I can drop `n` and `15*k`?

UPDATE: according to this [link](http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf) Big O is not valid notation for two or more variables

Comment: I'm not sure that you can, because either `k` or `n` could be massive in terms of the other.

Comment: True, but you can still compare terms based on each individually

Comment: @HackerBoss I'm sorry what do you mean by "True"? Do you mean I can drop only 15 constant?

Comment: I mean, as in my answer, that you still will end up with an n term and a k term. To comment on the link provided above, they assume that the function decreases at infinitely many points. That is not true if we assume that k and n are positive, as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
O(n^2+n+k^2+15*k)=O(n^2+n)+O(k^2+15*k)=O(n^2)+O(k^2)=O(n^2+k^2)
```

This does assume that k and n are both positive, looking at the behavior as they get large.

Comment: Could you provide a proof link or book where I can read more about it?